# How do I calculate the full configuration interaction Hamiltonian of H2

Tags: computational-chemistry, electronic-configuration

I have been trying to follow the paper titled "Towards Quantum Chemistry on a Quantum Computer" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0887.pdf) by simulating their results on a quantum computer simulator. Unfortunately, I have been having trouble classically calculating the full configuration interaction Hamiltonian for H2 using the STO-3G basis set. In the paper they use Pyquante, but I haven't been able to find good documentation on how to use it. I would be grateful if someone could show me how to calculate this using Pyquante, point me towards better documentation for Pyquante (I've only been able to find the rather poor documentation found here: http://pyquante.sourceforge.net/), or suggest a different/free quantum chemistry program that is easier to use.

For reference, I have been using Szabo and Ostlund's "Modern Quantum Chemistry: Introduction to Advanced Electronic Structure Theory" to try to get a handle on this calculation. They come up with two single-electron molecular wavefunctions,

[image]

and

[image]

where [image] and [image] are the 1S orbitals about each of the atoms.

This gives 4 molecular spin orbitals and thus 6 different Slater determinant basis states. These are the basis states for which I would like to calculate the Hamiltonian.

Comment: They have a cookbook with examples... http://pyquante.sourceforge.net/#cookbook

Comment: If you use Mac or Linux (or Linux subsystem on windows), I would recommend [Psi4](http://www.psicode.org). I have only used it a little, but it has CI implemented and they have pretty straightforward tutorials on [Github](https://github.com/psi4/psi4numpy/tree/master/Configuration-Interaction) for how to make a CI code

Comment: "They" may be one too many - I am not sure pyquante is actively developed...

Comment: @NightWriter I linked that source in my question, and (so far as I could tell) it didn't tell me how to solve my problem. Could you explain to me how I could use some of the code from the cookbook to find the full CI Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Tyberius Unfortunately I am on a windows system. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the Psi4 project provides a windows installer. Regarding CI under Pyquante, it looks like that was on the "to do" list for that project.

Comment: @LucasMyers I have used it with Windows, but it seems to require the Linux Subsystem. This is actually pre-installed on any Windows computer from the last few years, you just need to enter the Microsoft store to activate the app. Its not a terribly difficult process. Once you install that and Psi4, you can either make program files directly in the subsystem or connect to a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org)

Comment: @Tyberius what exactly is the app called? When I search "Linux Subsystem" in the Microsoft store a bunch of random distros pop up. And would I need to do anything extra to interface a Jupyter Notebook with psi4?

Comment: WSL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: @LucasMyers You could use pretty much any of them, though I happened to use Ubuntu. If I'm remembering right, the install instructions on Jupyter's website should be enough. Installing psi4 also installs python and anaconda so you can perform any of the python related installation instructions. Once you have done all that, psi4 is a python import that can be used in any code you write in the subsystem or in a connected Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Tyberius Just one more clarification question -- I've activated the Linux Subsystem and installed the Ubuntu command window. Are you suggesting that I download conda in the Ubuntu command window and use that to download Psi4? And if so, will I be able to use Psi4 in a Jupyter Notebook on my regular machine? Or will I somehow have to also download Jupyter in the command window to use Psi4?

Comment: @LucasMyer Installing psi4 will also install a version of Python and Anaconda. You can then either use psi4 directly or import it in Python code as a module. Jupyter is nice to have, but not strictly necessary.